# Moving object 2d with viewmatrix

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

I'm working on a small game based on the movements of the military in ww2. I first started to make a camera to look around and then I wrote a programm to slowly move a platoon towarts where i clicked and then stop if it was there. UNtil there everything works totally fine, but then I tried to get it to work while having moved the camera so the matrix wasn't the standard matrix. I haven't got the mooving of the platoon to the right location to work.
I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me what I have to do to get it working

moving Code:

```
    public void Update(MouseState mouse, GameTime gameTime,Matrix matrix)
    {

        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            mousePos = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);
            Vector2.Transform(mousePos, matrix);
            oldPos = testObjPos;
            Vector2.Transform(oldPos, matrix);
            Difference = mousePos - oldPos;

            Difference.Normalize();
        }
        testObjPos += Difference * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 20;
        if (testObjPos.X > mousePos.X - 1 && testObjPos.X < mousePos.X + 1 &&
            testObjPos.Y > mousePos.Y - 1 && testObjPos.Y < mousePos.Y + 1)
            Difference = new Vector2(0, 0);

    }
```

and maybe my camera class is the problem
Camera COde

```
    float moveSpeed = 300;
    Vector2 position;
    Matrix viewMatrix;
    int screenwidth, screenheight;
   public void Update(KeyboardState keyState, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            position.Y -= moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            position.Y += moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            position.X -= moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            position.X += moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (position.X < -1000)
            position.X = -1000;
        if (position.Y < -1000)
            position.Y = -1000;
        if (position.X > 1000)
            position.X = 1000;
        if (position.Y > 1000)
            position.Y = 1000;
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-position, 0));
    }
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at it already.

Comment: I don't know C# so its probably something obvious, but why does `Difference` start with a capital? Its not a class name, its an instance of an object or a variable in the way you appear to be using it. Perhaps `Difference` is the name of an actual class in XNA or one of your libraries?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it seems it was just me naming my variables sloppy. it was the variable.

Comment: Oh alright, just was noticing. Now I got curious and did some [research on C# variable naming conventions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/name-convention-for-variables-in-c), and it appears I gave you some bad advice. Apparently, `Pascal` case (aka what you used), is acceptable. I'm rather used to Java where `camelCase` is the preferred form for class instances and variables. My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `matrix` is your view matrix. This matrix is used to transform positions from world space to camera space.

Your mouse position is in view space and you want to transform it to world space, hence in the other way. Therefore, you need the inverse of `matrix`. Furthermore, the `Vector2.Transform()` method returns the transformed vector. It does not change the original one. So right now, you don't use any transformed positions:

```
var invMatrix = Matrix.Invert(matrix);
mousePos = Vector2.Transform(mousePos, invMatrix);
```

You probably do not want to transform oldPos because it already is in world space (probably, I can't tell definitely from the code snippet).

By the way, there is an easier way to check if `testObjPos` is near `mousePos`. Just check the length of the difference vector:

```
if((testObjPos - mousePos).Length() < 1)
    //stop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm now with vacation in Canada and can't try it, but you've given me hope